# How to trim input text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

**Issue:** How to trim text using `asp-for` tag & razor page?

**Detail:** I have a input field where user can enter there `firstname`. I noticed user can enter multi spaces or tabs. Since I am using `asp-for` tag, it will auto bind the data to `Person` object  on `OnPost()` Method

**I am trying not to use** following methods `Request.Form("firstname").trim()` or pass value though `OnPost(string firstname)` Method; Because whole point of `asp-for` tag is to auto bind your values to object rather than manually getting each values like using `name` tag.

If there isn't any way to do this, than what is the point of `asp.for` tag? bc in real world you will end up checking for extra spaces any ways.

```
<input asp-for="Person.FirstName"  />
<span asp-validation-for="Person.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>

     [BindProperty]
    public Person_Model Person { get; set; } = default!;
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string? FirstName{ get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        // here First_name can have spaces
        _context2.my_DbSet.Add(Person);
        await _context2.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

public class Person_Model
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    public string? FirstName{ get; set; }
 }
```

**I tried** adding RegularExpression, but this will just give me error if there is whtie space inside text-field. I just want to trim it.

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^\s]+")]
public string? FirstName{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using RegularExpression but that will give me error if there is a white space inside text field. I just want to trim it bc if user add extra space than there shouldnt be an error. just trim `"   Dave"` or `" Dave"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended method for centralising trimming of input strings is to create a custom model binder which does this as part of the model binding process.

Create a class called TrimModelBinder:

```
public class TrimModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(valueProviderResult.FirstValue?.Trim());
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Create a ModelBinderProvider that returns your new model binder if the binding target is a string:

```
public class TrimModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(TrimModelBinder));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Register this with the services container:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc(options => options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new TrimModelBinderProvider()));
```

Now you no longer have to call `Trim()` on every input string.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in case the FirstName is a required field, you have to add the Required attribute.

```
public class Person_Model
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your OnPostAsync method you first have to check for validation errors and return to page in order to display the error messages.

You can also trim your FirstName if you want and then continue saving the record in your database.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    // validate the model. in case there are validation errors return to page and display them
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    // trim your first name in case there are spaces
    Person.FirstName = Person.FirstName?.Trim();

    // here First_name can have spaces
    _context2.my_DbSet.Add(Person);
    await _context2.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Page();
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, this works. I have about 30 input field so I was trying to avoid doing this 30 times. but I think there isnt any other way of doing it. Ill just use your sollution